# Replace analytics tracking code wtih regex

Tags: php, regex, aptana

I need to do a huge replacement on my site 400+ items with the new asynchronous tracking.

```
pageTracker._trackEvent('footer_search', 'search', 'search-footer');
```

Im using aptana and it has a regex replacement, it needs to look like this, notice the [ ].

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'footer_search', 'search', 'search-footer']);
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

search for

```
pageTracker._trackEvent\('([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', '([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', '([A-Za-z0-9-_-]+)'\);
```

replace with

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '$1', '$2', '$3']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you can see where I'm going with this.

```
pageTracker\.([^\(]+)\(([^\)]+)\)

_gaq.push(['$1', $2]);
```